# How to import russian user records in salesforce?

Tags: data-loader, csv, data-migration

I am trying to load the csv files data through data loader to salesforce,When i try to load the Russian data i get `??????` in the place of text .How to resolve this issue??

Answer (score 4):

Once you save the file in excel in CSV Format, Open it in notepad and save it with encoding as UTF-8, Open it again in excel to see if character are appearing correctly. If Yes then load the file .

Assuming that dataloader is used to load this data in, then ensure that utf8 is checked within the settings

Comment: I have checked following your steps ...but i still get ??? marks in place of Russian text...it may be tht my office tool is not supporting Russian language??

Comment: Dont open in excel then ...Just directly load the CSV without opening it in Excel.The problem that happens is excel may not support the Russian character

Comment: I need to edit the data ...I tried with open office where it accepts Russian language but once i reopen that document  it shows some special characters instead of original data. Salesforce also shows the same special character

Answer (score 0):

It worked with open office it is not possible to do using MS office tool.Before loading the data check wheather the utf-8 is accepted by the data loader in Data loader setting.